# Getting the "Open With" Box When I try to Open Any Folder

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, file-management

I hope someone can help me with this problem that's just occurred, I've never seen it before and I'm stumped as to what's causing it. Basically whenever I try and open any folder on the PC, whether it be network or local it asks me what I want to open it with.

Have any of you seen this error before?

Comment: There's a particular virus that does this.  http://superuser.com for the win.

Comment: I had this two years ago and fixed it. Once I'm free of my work proxy I'll try and find the solution online again.

Answer (score 1):

Use Doug Knox' **[Folder Association Fix](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/file_assoc.htm)** to restore the default associations for file folders.

Answer (score 0):

Can you highlight the folder with a single click, then hit 'enter' to open it?  How about right-clicking with the keyboard button?

I recently had a laptop with a faulty trackpad.  Using a USB mouse resolved the issue until I could send back for repair.

So..maybe its a hardware issue.